# How can I draw a line in a printer that looks thinner than a pixel?

Tags: windows, printing, gdi

I know the GDI limitation. GDI can only draw line which width is at least 1 pixel. But I still want to draw a line which looks thinner than 1 pixel in a printer.

Do you mean I can do it like this:

```
with cLogBrush do
begin
    lbStyle := BS_Solid;
    lbColor := ACanvas.Pen.Color;
    lbHatch := 0;
end;  
dwStyle := PS_COSMETIC or PS_ALTERNATE;
ACanvas.Pen.Handle := ExtCreatePen(dwStyle, 1, cLogBrush, 0, nil);
ACanvas.MoveTo(X1, Y1);
ACanvas.LineTo(X2, Y2);
```

Comment: I'm going to take your word that GDI and printing deals with pixels and not other units. You could try using dithering to fake the line weight.

Answer (score 0):

You could (for example) draw a line of alternating black and white pixels. At least with a typical laser printer at 600 to 1200 DPI, this will normally blend pretty well into a line that looks less dark. I should add, however, that a line only one pixel wide from a good laser printer really is pretty thin.

A lot here does depend on the printer though. Just for example, with most ink jet printers, the thinnest line you can draw is thicker, even when/if they quote the same (or even higher) resolution. The lines usually aren't quite as clean either -- in both cases, they're darkest at the center, and fade to the paper color, but with an ink jet that "fade" is usually quite a bit slower so the edges of the line aren't as clean.

Comment: Do you mean I can do it like this: